# How to format route that gives user back based on username

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose

This is my API call in Angular:

```
$http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "http://groep6api.herokuapp.com/user",
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                transformRequest: function(obj) {
                    var str = [];
                    for(var p in obj)
                        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                    return str.join("&");
                },
                data: {username: "testeken3"}
            }).success(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            });
```

This is my route in routes/index.js:

```
router.post('/user', function(req, res, next){
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

  User.find(function(user){
    if(user.username != req.body.username){next(err);}
    res.json(user);
  });
});
```

My API call is correct I think, but how does my route needs to look like?
This just gives no response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using `mongoose` for your ODM, you're not passing any conditions to your `User.find()` function. Additionally, the callback passed to `find()` is an error first callback so the first param will be assigned an `Error` object if one occurs, if not it will be undefined and the second parameter will contain the results of `find()`.

The below code uses [`find()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) to locate the given user based on username and then depending on what is passed to the callback will respond accordingly. This code also assumes that the `username` has a unique constraint on the property. If not, this code would return all results that matched the conditions of `find()`.

```
router.post('/user', function(req, res, next){
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

  User.find({ username: req.body.username}, function(err, user){
    if(err)
      return next(err);

    if (user) // check the value returned for undefined
      res.status(200).json(user);
    else
      res.status(204).send();
  });      
});
```